# Spring data mongodb group aggregation object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to group a object based on a query with spring data and mongodb, that's what i do till now:

**Mongodb data:**

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58af31feef34aa45476d2be9"),
 "_class" : "my.model.Image",
 "file" : "0006000.jpg",
 "number" : "123",
 "mkdius" : "Fiscalization 432",
 "status" : "UNCOMPLETED",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-23T16:03:26.612-03:00")
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58af31feef34aa45476d2bf3"),
 "_class" : "my.model.Image",
 "file" : "9781.jpg",
 "number" : "987",
 "mkdius" : "Fiscalization 432",
 "status" : "UNCOMPLETED",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-23 16:03:26.866-03:00")
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58af31feef34aa45476d2bea"),
 "_class" : "my.model.Image",
 "file" : "00016.jpg",
 "number" : "432",
 "mkdius" : "Fiscalization 4154",
 "status" : "UNCOMPLETED",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-23T16:03:26.835-03:00")
}
```

**My aggregation function:**

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("status").is(Status.UNCOMPLETED)), // Match
    Aggregation.group("mkdius").last("mkdius").as("mkdius").addToSet("id").as("imgsId"), // Grouping
    Aggregation.project("imgsId").and("cd").previousOperation()); // Projecting

AggregationResults<InitApp.result> groupResults = this.mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Image.class, InitApp.result.class);

groupResults.getMappedResults().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Result that i got:**

```
InitApp.result(mkdius=Fiscalization 432, imgIds=[58af31feef34aa45476d2be9,58af31feef34aa45476d2bf3]

InitApp.result(mkdius=Fiscalization 4154, imgIds=[58af31feef34aa45476d2bea]
```

**What i expect:**

```
InitApp.result(mkdius=Fiscalization 432, imgs=[{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58af31feef34aa45476d2be9"),
 "_class" : "my.model.Image",
 "file" : "0006000.jpg",
 "number" : "123",
 "mkdius" : "Fiscalization 432",
 "status" : "UNCOMPLETED",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-23T16:03:26.612-03:00")
},{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58af31feef34aa45476d2bf3"),
 "_class" : "my.model.Image",
 "file" : "9781.jpg",
 "number" : "987",
 "mkdius" : "Fiscalization 432",
 "status" : "UNCOMPLETED",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-23 16:03:26.866-03:00")
}]

InitApp.result(cd=Fiscalization 4154, imgs=[{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58af31feef34aa45476d2bea"),
 "_class" : "my.model.Image",
 "file" : "00016.jpg",
 "number" : "432",
 "mkdius" : "Fiscalization 4154",
 "status" : "UNCOMPLETED",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-23T16:03:26.835-03:00")
}]
```

I don't know if it's possible to do, aggregate the data and put the current object in the response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `$group` stage with

```
Aggregation.group("mkdius").last("mkdius").as("mkdius").push("$$ROOT").as("imgsId"),
```

[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) will push the whole document.